# Deep Learning model to predict the coordinates of the vertices of a polygon given its centroid

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, coordinate-systems

I am required to come up with a Deep Learning model which takes a vector as input and predicts the 3D coordinates of the vertices of the n-sided polygon (where n can vary from 3 to 10). The input vector passes through the centroid of the polygon and is perpendicular to the plane of the polygon.

Given this problem, I have two major questions:

1. Is it possible to devise such a model which can predict all vertices of the polygon given ONLY the vector described above? If not, what additional features are required?
2. What is the best neural network based model which can help solve this problem? I was thinking that the output layer of the architecture must have 3*n neurons (3 for each of the 3D coordinates of the n vertices). How do I take care of the output layer, given that n can be variable?